# objective-c NSURLCredentialStorage and removeCredential not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this method here that is a logout method and is suppose to clear my session created by:

```
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential
                                   credentialWithUser:user
                                   password:password
                                   persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
```

The issue is that the creds are not being cleared...if I put a break point at the end of the method and run my code it works, but without the break point it does not work, here is the method:

```
- (void)LogoutButtonPressed
{

    //@TODO: Fix Logout
    /*NSURLCredentialStorage *credentialStorage = [NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage];
    NSDictionary *credentialsDicationary = [credentialStorage allCredentials];


    for (NSURLProtectionSpace *space in [credentialsDicationary allKeys]) {

        NSDictionary *spaceDictionary = [credentialsDicationary objectForKey:space];

        for (id userName in [spaceDictionary allKeys]) {

            NSURLCredential *credential = [spaceDictionary objectForKey:userName];

            [credentialStorage removeCredential:credential forProtectionSpace:space];

        }

    }*/

    // reset the credentials cache...
    NSDictionary *credentialsDict = [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] allCredentials];

    if ([credentialsDict count] > 0) {
        // the credentialsDict has NSURLProtectionSpace objs as keys and dicts of userName => NSURLCredential
        NSEnumerator *protectionSpaceEnumerator = [credentialsDict keyEnumerator];
        id urlProtectionSpace;

        // iterate over all NSURLProtectionSpaces
        while (urlProtectionSpace = [protectionSpaceEnumerator nextObject]) {
            NSEnumerator *userNameEnumerator = [[credentialsDict objectForKey:urlProtectionSpace] keyEnumerator];
            id userName;

            // iterate over all usernames for this protectionspace, which are the keys for the actual NSURLCredentials
            while (userName = [userNameEnumerator nextObject]) {
                NSURLCredential *cred = [[credentialsDict objectForKey:urlProtectionSpace] objectForKey:userName];
                NSLog(@"cred to be removed: %@", cred);
                [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] removeCredential:cred forProtectionSpace:urlProtectionSpace];
            }
        }
    }


    [loginMenuView setFrame:CGRectMake(loginMenuView.frame.origin.x, loginMenuView.frame.origin.y, 410, 184)];
    [logingMetalBg setFrame:CGRectMake(loginMenuView.bounds.origin.x, loginMenuView.bounds.origin.y, loginMenuView.bounds.size.width, loginMenuView.bounds.size.height)];
    /*LHAppDelegate *appDelegate = (LHAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.loginSession setString:@""];
    [appDelegate.nameOfUser setString:@""];*/
    [logoutButton removeFromSuperview];
    logoutButton = nil;
    //[[logoutPopup getPopOver ]dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
    //logoutPopup = nil;
    [settingsPage hide];
    [self.menu removeFromSuperview];
    self.menu = nil;
    menuItems = nil;
    [self MenuOrLogin];

}
```

I got this code from this example:

http://www.springenwerk.com/2008/11/i-am-currently-building-iphone.html

What Am I Doing wrong ?

also the code in the method throughs a warning:

```
/Users/jsuske/Documents/SSiPad(Device Only)ios7/SchedulingiPadApplication/ViewControllers/LHLoginController.m:523:105: Local declaration of 'userName' hides instance variable
```

Why is this happening ?

Comment: You get the warning because you use a local property `userName` and already implemented a global property with the same name.

Comment: renaming them got rid of the warnings.